# MONGODB in php ok but not shows in my console

Tags: php, mongodb, shell

I have MongoDB configurated in PHP and all is ok, I do inserts, finds, etc... The problem is when I want view the database in my console, the databases not exist!!
I don't understand, in my php code I can view all data but in my console not exist.

Php:

```
public function conectar(){
      return $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  }

  public function guardarLog($nombre, $mensaje, $idReserva=null, $agencia='0'){
    $manager = $this->conectar();
    $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
    $bulk->insert([
      'log' => [$nombre => $mensaje, 'idReserva' => $idReserva, 'agencia' => $agencia, 'fecha' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]
    ]);

    $manager->executeBulkWrite('db.aaaa', $bulk);
  }
```

My console:

```
show databases
```

Comment: I have no errors, only I can't view de data by database. I trying use aaaa and db.aaaa.log.find() and nothing..

Comment: the database not exist

Comment: --db mongodb://localhost:27017 ?? 
waits without results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118991/discussion-between-mohsin-patel-and-jordi-salom).